# Property pattern matching ignore case

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

Is there a way to do property pattern matching with ignore case?

I have a code which is using pattern matching order a list.

```
private string InventorySortKeySelector(Inventory Inventory)
        {
            return Inventory switch
            {
                { LocationCode: "Location1" } when Inventory.SubLocationCode.In("67", "96") => $"{Inventory.LocationCode}_{Inventory.SubLocationCode}_{Inventory.Number}",
                { LocationCode: "Location2" } => $"Location2_ElseWhere_{Inventory.Number}",
                { LocationCode: "ElseWhere" } => $"Location2_ElseWhere_{Inventory.Number}x",
                _ => $"{Inventory.LocationCode}_{Inventory.Number}"
            };
        }
```

I am able to achieve it using following:

```
private string InventorySortKeySelector(Inventory Inventory)
{
    const string Location2ElseWhere = "Location2_ElseWhere";
    const string Location2 = "Location2";
    const string Location1 = "Location1";
    const string ElseWhere = "ElseWhere";

    return Inventory?.LocationCode?.ToUpperInvariant() switch
    {
        Location1 when Inventory.SubLocationCode.In("67", "96") =>
            $"{Inventory.LocationCode}_{Inventory.SubLocationCode}_{Inventory.Number}",
        Location2 => $"{Location2ElseWhere}_{Inventory.Number}",
        ElseWhere => $"{Location2ElseWhere}_{Inventory.Number}x",
        _ => $"{Inventory?.LocationCode}_{Inventory?.Number}"
    };
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to handle this scenario?

**Edit:**

Using current solution , I am now limited to just one property.

This will not work if I want to use multiple properties and still want to use ignore case.

Ex:

```
private string InventorySortKeySelector(Inventory Inventory)
            {
                return Inventory switch
                {
                    { LocationCode: "Location1", ZipCode: "1111" } when Inventory.SubLocationCode.In("67", "96") => $"{Inventory.LocationCode}_{Inventory.SubLocationCode}_{Inventory.Number}",
                    { LocationCode: "Location2", ZipCode: "2222" } => $"Location2_ElseWhere_{Inventory.Number}",
                    { LocationCode: "ElseWhere", ZipCode: "3333" } => $"Location2_ElseWhere_{Inventory.Number}x",
                    _ => $"{Inventory.LocationCode}_{Inventory.Number}"
                };
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"?

Comment: I mean if could do pass a an option when destructing the variable.  In-case , I will want to use multiple properties, I am limited with current approach.

Comment: I really have no idea what you just said. Could you rephrase?

Comment: My bad, Just did an edit to the question.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to use an equality comparer with a switch expression. Alternatives would be to convert your input string to all lower/upper, and the same with the strings to match, or use a dictionary.

Comment: @JonasH, Can understand switching them to all lower or upper. Can you please explain about using a dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary is somewhat similar to a switch expression in that both take some key, and produce a value. A dictionary does take a `IEqualityComparer`, letting you ignore casing, but it does not support all the other features of switches, like filters etc. But it depend on how many cases you need to handle, if there is only three, just go with separate `if`s. If there are *many*, you might consider a dictionary read from file, even if it is more complicated, or even better, a database.